# Shell with coloring and showing the git branch?

Tags: command-line, prompt

My friend has installed some kind of a shell for terminal and on that machine i can see in which branch I am at the moment. It looks like this:

[image]

And now i want to install that on another machine but i don't know the name of it. I hope someone will recognize it from the screenshot.

Comment: @lewis4u why not add it to the duplicate? If you mean the classic `__git_ps1` script, that would be a great answer for the dupe.

Comment: Uhm. OK. But please make the question specific to zsh then.

Comment: not for the entire thing, no. Of course, the vast majority of what you posted is completely irrelevant here. But I don't have the time to go through it and pick out the useful bits. Using that thing just to get your branch displayed is like using a tank to kill a fly. But yeah, it does that too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a `zsh` shell

install it with apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

download the theme

```
wget -O ~/.zshrc https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grml/grml-etc-core/master/etc/zsh/zshrc
```

change the default shell (please note that you will lose your aliases with this)

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

#### update for aliases

if you have aliases in a separate file in your `home/<user_name>` folder then append this to the end of the `.zshrc` file in your `home/<user_name>` folder

```
if [ -f ~/.aliases_file ]; then
     . ~/.aliases_file
fi
```